# Excel to relational database - Access 2007

Tags: excel, database-design, ms-access

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARbfh.jpg

So I've got a large flat file database which I need to normalize.  The pic above is the PK of a patient record, and the text are associated codes.  I'm looking to make that into a junction table.  The text codes are the primary keys of another table, with a text representation of what they mean.

```
1 9654
1 7840
1 28260
1 4375
2 8409
2 etc.
```

So as you can see I need a number in the top row for every code in a 1 to 1 manner.  I know this can be done without this brute force way, what's the best?

The regular flat file has code 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...20 as columns, and of course for many patients the records are blank, what's the best way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ADO in Excel, or link the Excel table to Access, after that a union query should enable you to create a link table.

Comment: Does Access not have an import option where you can define what variables are to be split into separate tables?  Maybe it's SQL Server that I'm thinking about.  Sound familiar?

Comment: You can set a range as the table in Access, certainly.

Comment: is this a one off or are you going to need to perform this on a regular basis.