# Multiple columns from a table into one, large column?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I don't know what in the world is the best way to go about this.  I have a very large array of columns, each one with 1-25 rows associated with it.  I need to be able to combine all into one large column, skipping blanks if at all possible.  Is this something that Access can do?

```
a   b   c   d   e  f  g  h 
3   0   1   1   1  1  1  5
3   5   6   8   8  3     5
    1   1   2   2  1     5 
    4   4   2   1  1     5
                   1     5
```

there are no blanks within each column, but each column has a different number of numbers in it. they need to be added from left to right so a,b, c, d, e, f.  And the 0 from be needs to be in the first blank cell after the second 3 in A.  And the first 5 in H needs to be directly after the 1 in g, with no blanks.

Comment: Isn't this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278699/excel-to-relational-database-access-2007/9278921#comment11698108_9278921 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want a result like:

```
3
3
0
5
1
4
1
6
1
4
```

etc?

Here is how I would approach the problem. Insert your array into a work table with an autonumber column (important to retain the order the data is in, databases do not guarnatee an order unless you can give them something to sort on) called id
as well as the array columns.

Create a final table with an autonumber column (see above note on why you need an automnumber) and the column you want as you final table.

Run a separate insert statment for each column in your work table and run them in the order you want the data.

so the inserts would look something like:

```
insert table2 (colA)
select columnA from table1 order by id

insert table2 (colA)
select columnB from table1 order by id

insert table2 (colA)
select columnC from table1 order by id
```

Now when you do `select columnA from table2 order by id` you should have the results you need.